# How to locate C, C++, and Fortran compilers on my win7x64 machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake, fortran, lapack

I'm trying to build binary files of the [LAPACK 3.7.0](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.7.0.html) using [CMAKE](https://cmake.org/) based on [what is told here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#build). In order to use them in my [Visual Studio 2013 C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494093/profiling-a-mex-function-through-visual-studio-to-find-its-interior-bottle-necks).
But I really don't know which option should I choose here?
[image]
And also which compilers should I choose in the following?
[image]
Because I can't find them in the suggested directories within `Program Files` or `Program File(x86)` folders.
my machine uses a dual-core `Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU`

Comment: If you are building using Visual Studio 2013 you should probably pick that one from the generator list. And how are you usually using the compilers? If via the command-line you could try using the `where` command to find the path

Comment: @UnholySheep yeah, I mean should I choose `Visual Studio 12 2013 win64` or `Visual Studio 12 2013`?

Comment: That depends on whether you are building a 32bit or 64bit project - you haven't specified that in your question

Comment: @UnholySheep It's a research-based project. I'm going to run it on my x64 machine only. so should I make a 64-bit project and choose `Visual Studio 12 2013 win64`?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for better visibility. Fortran 90 is just one specific (and old) version.

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio < 2015, a common solution is to run CMake GUI from Visual Studio Command line.

Use windows start menu to run "Visual Studio Command Prompt"

[image: start menu]

Run cmake-gui from command line. If the folder is in your path, simply launch cmake-gui. If not, launch it using the full path

[image: msvc command prompt]

Locate the source folder of your project (the folder containing the top-level CMakeLists.txt) and create a new build folder (ex c:/my-project/build_32). Generating an environment in the source folder is discouraged)
Generate your project selecting the right MSVC version. In your case, it will be "Visual Studio 12 2013". In my case, this is MSVC 2010.

[image: cmake generation]

That's all. Click on finish button and it should generate the compilation environment, solutions, projetcs, etc.

This will generate environment for compiling x86 application. If you also need to compile a x64 version of your project, simply follow again that process, generating in a new build folder and selection "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64".

By default, if you have a paid version of Visual Studio you have both x86 and Win64 compiler installed. If you have the express version, you only have the x86 compiler (so generation using MSVC Win64 will fail).

Comment: About the second part, [the page](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#build) strictly suggest to `click "Specify native compilers" and indicate the path to the ifort compiler`  .

Comment: Answer updated with 32/64 bits information. Basically, you will have to generate twice, in 2 separate folders, to compile your project in 32 AND 64 bits.

Comment: For the second part, you have to install Intel compiler on your machine. The link you provided said `Requirements: Visual Studio, Intel C and Fortran Compilers, CMAKE 2.8.12`

Comment: I couldn't find visual studio 2013 command prompt through search field in the start menu but when I locate to `Visual Studio 2013> tools` in my all programs list, there's [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzVh5.png) added to the question, too. should I choose one of them? Then which one? `The developer command prompt`, `X64 native tools/cross tools`

Comment: Are intel C and fortran compilers free to download? [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-compilers), I don't see an Intel C compiler, though. Just Intel C++ and Fortran compilers

Comment: The community edition comes with the x64 compiler, no need to resort to the paid version.

Comment: @Banex oops, getting the error `cannot determine the location for VS common tools folder` when I choose the `Developer command prompt for vs 2013`. I didn't mention Antwane because he'll be notified by default

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity. Does compiling a C++ project through `Intel C++ compiler` instead of `Visual Studio` effect substantially the performance of the program?

Comment: In my experience, yes, on extensive floating point number computations. You can find many comparative tests on the internet. Also, read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151375/are-intel-compilers-really-better-than-the-microsoft-ones

Comment: And LAPACK certainly qualifies as extensive FP number crunching. http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/98665/8434